# SQL Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: sql, mariadb

If i run the SQL command below i always get this error:

> Invalid SQL: CREATE TABLE ms_account (accountid INT NOT NULL auto_increment,accountname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,kindofaccount SMALLINT NOT NULL,accountowner VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,accountcurrency VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,accountbalance DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL,bankid VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,createdate INT NOT NULL,deletedate INT NOT NULL,changedate INT NOT NULL,deleted SMALLINT NOT NULL,locked SMALLINT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY accountid (bankid,accountid)) ; : Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

SQL

```
"CREATE TABLE {$utcv_db_prefix}account (".
"accountid INT NOT NULL auto_increment,".
"accountname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,".
"kindofaccount SMALLINT NOT NULL,".
"accountowner VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,".
"accountcurrency VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,".
"accountbalance DECIMAL(15,2) NOT NULL,".
"bankid VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,".
"createdate INT NOT NULL,".
"deletedate INT NOT NULL,".
"changedate INT NOT NULL,".
"deleted SMALLINT NOT NULL,".
"locked SMALLINT NOT NULL,".
"PRIMARY KEY (bankid,accountid)".
") $utcv_db_create_extension;";
```

i already tried to add primary key to `"accountid INT NOT NULL auto_increment,".` but that only returns the error multiple primary keys

Comment: What database provider are you using?

Comment: Good question.  Some databases allow for multiple keys like you're trying.  Some only allow the one.

Comment: @IanO'Brien i use some free webspace at bplaced.net. Server: bplaced MySQL-Database Interface (Localhost via UNIX socket)
Server-Typ: MariaDB
Server Version: 5.5.33a-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protokoll-Version: 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your auto increment column (by itself) must be the primary key of the table.

**edit**

After doing a little reading, I think it needs to be a key of any type, not necessarily a primary key.

Try adding "KEY(accountid)" or "UNIQUE KEY (accountid)".

Comment: i thought about that too, but my problem is, that that file is not by me. it's part of a big project i'm trying to install and i don't know if i can change it without messing up the whole thing

Comment: Worked for me too on MariaDB. I confirm I had to add a KEY(MyAutoIncrementField) before the PRIMARY KEY(Field1, ..., MyAutoIncrementField)